# Bug in C++20 concepts with template member functions and std::invocable

Tags: c++, eigen, c++20, concept, invocable

I was experimenting with C++20 concepts and the [Eigen library](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), and I incurred an unexpected behavior. Specifically, consider the following concept requiring a type to be callable with either an `Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>>` object or an `Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1>>` one:

```
template <class FOO_CONCEPT>
concept FooConcept = std::invocable<FOO_CONCEPT, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>> &&
    std::invocable<FOO_CONCEPT, Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1>>;
```

Then, look at the commented line (*) in the following struct:

```
struct Foo {
    // template <typename T>    <----    (*)
    void operator()(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>) {
    }

    void operator()(Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>) {
    }
};
```

Note that the class `Foo` doesn't satisfy the requirements of `FooConcept` since it can't be called with an `Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1>` argument. Indeed:

```
std::cout << FooConcept<Foo> << std::endl;
```

prints `0`. However, when I toggle the line comment (*), i.e., when the `operator()` is a template, the same code oddly prints `1`. Is this a bug? I got these results both using Clang 12.0.1 and GCC 11.1.0 to compile the code on Visual Studio Code. Thank you for any help you can provide!

P.S.: the line

```
 std::cout << std::is_convertible<Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>>()
              << std::endl;
```

prints `1`, but an `Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1>` object cannot be implicitly converted into an `Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>`. Is this another bug? And is this correlated to the above problem somehow?

---

EDIT 1: I noticed that by defining

```
struct FooImplicit {
    void operator()(Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1>) {
    }
};
```

the `FooImplicit` struct actually satisfies the `FooConcept`, and the same happens if you replace `char` with `double`. This looks related to the convertibility of the two Eigen types -- see P.S.

**How can I express the constraint I want without allowing implicit conversions?** That is, `FooConcept` must allow *only* classes that overload `operator()` *at least* twice, once with `Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>` and once with `Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1>`. Can this be done?

Also, if I define the function

```
void func(FooConcept auto x) {}
```

and I try to call it as `func(Foo());` keeping the line (*) commented, I get the following compile error:

```
[build] [...]: note: because 'Foo' does not satisfy 'FooConcept'
[build] void func(FooConcept auto x) {
[build]               ^
[build] [...]: note: because 'std::invocable<Foo, Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1> >' evaluated to false
```

**Is this because the compiler cannot choose unambiguously which overload to call? If yes, why isn't the error message more explicit?** To me, it looks just like the compiler noticed that `Foo` has two member functions, and one is correct, whereas the other one isn't.

---

EDIT 2: I managed to answer half of the question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67404736/15826299). However, I'm still curious about the error message I got from the compiler.

Comment: "*prints 1, but an Eigen::Matrix<char, -1, 1> object cannot be implicitly converted into an Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>.*" What makes you so sure about that? C++ seems to think it is, and it's generally correct about the code you give it.

Comment: I tested it personally; Eigen makes you explicitly cast between different matrix types!

Comment: `std::is_convertible` reports `true` - but `Eigen` has a `static_assert` preventing the conversion, so `Eigen` is not SFINAE friendly in that sense.

Answer (score 4):

`is_convertable` merely determines if the overload exists and can be found unambigouously.  In Eigen's case, the overload converting between those types exists, but the body has a `static_assert`.

`is_convertable` does *not* instantiate the body of the conversion operation before saying it works.  This is intentional, to permit C++ overload resolution to not require compiling a huge amount of code.

For your traits to work, Eigen needs to be rewitten to support "SFINAE"-friendly methods and conversion operators.

The failure in your test was because the char matrix converted to both, which is ambiguous, so the trait fails.  This isn't why you thought it failed.

Adding the `template<class T>` means that overload isn't considered (T cannot be deduced), so converting to an array of float is unambiguously selected.

Comment: I think I understood the first part of your answer, and it seems reasonable, so thanks!

"*The failure i your test was because the char matrix converted to both, which is ambiguous, so the trait fails. This isn't why you thought it failed.*"

I'm not sure about this statement, please refer to the EDIT in the main question.

"*Adding the template<class T> means that overload isn't considered (T cannot be deduced), so converting to an array of float is unambiguously selected.*"

This statement looks correct if the previous one is. Please refer once again to the EDIT in the main question!

Comment: As a follow-up comment, when I add *both* the `template<class T>` and a template specialization `template <> void operator()<double>(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>) {}`, I still get that `Foo` satisfies the `FooConcept`, which is something I wouldn't expect. The overload selection by the compiler should be ambiguous also in this case, shouldn't it?

Comment: @fdev I am pretty sure that template specializations do not play a role in overload resolution. Hence, adding one does not make a difference.

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: OK, I assume you're referring to this [concept](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=only-overloading-function-templates-c). Nice!